# Add JSXText node to array of children

Tags: babeljs, jsx, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to write a Babel plugin that will insert some whitespace (either a space or `/n`) after each JSX node in the `children` array of a parent JSX node. So:

```
<svg><path/><path/></svg>
```

becomes:

```
<svg> <path/> <path/> </svg>
```

or even:

```
<svg>
    <path/>
    <path/>
</svg>
```

After reading the [Babel Handbook section on inserting siblings](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#inserting-a-sibling-node), I thought this would be pretty straightforward. But, it looks like `insertAfter` requires you to provide an `Expression`, but I just want to insert a `JSXText` node.

Is there a better way to work with JSX nodes? I was contemplating just iterating over children and building a new array with the `JSXText` nodes added in and then replacing `children`, but wasn't sure if that was a good idea.

**Edit:** [Here's a link to what I tried on AST Explorer.](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/c4d682a0e37486555dba237c4b343496/5f28ec49321d6e41a2764ff90d0eacd94f65c78d) That's based off of what the docs say to do, but I think I need to be inserting a JSXText node, instead. But if I do that it errors out because I guess a JSXText node isn't an expression?

Comment: It might help if you could throw what you've tried into a transform example on http://astexplorer.net/. You can toggle "transform" on there and then save a functional example.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks for the tip - just updated with a link.